# Como ler um ficheiro se o nome do mesmo está guardado numa variável?

Tags: r, for, read.table

Eu tenho um ficheiro com nomes de outros ficheiros 980 na verdade, entao eu queria ler esse ficheiro e ir guardando os nomes numa variável e a seguir abrir o ficheiro com esse nome, tentei com o read table mas como o nome está numa variável ele não reconhece. Alguma solução para isto?

```
s <- Filename[i,1]
c <-  read.table(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que todos os arquivos tenham a mesma estrutura de variáveis e que possam ser mesclados entre si, o código abaixo deve funcionar. Se os arquivos importados forem xls, ou outro formato, podem ser parametrizados pela própria função de importação. Neste exemplo, cada arquivo possuía apenas 1 linha e duas variáveis.

```
# adiciona o nome dos arquivos do diretório no vetor "arquivos"
arquivos <- dir()

print(arquivos) 
# "1.txt" "2.txt" "3.txt"

# cria um data.frame que será a base 
base <- data.frame(read.table(arquivos[1]))

head(base)
#   V1 V2
# 1 10 11

# faz o laço de todos os arquivos seguintes
for(i in 2:length(arquivos)){
  base2 <- data.frame(read.table(arquivos[i]))
  base <- rbind(base, base2)
}

head(base)
#   V1 V2
# 1 10 11
# 2 20 21
# 3 30 31
```